# PDO gives access denied error when running PHP in command line but works in Apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, command-line-interface

I'm facing a strange problem while doing maintenance in a code that was working flawlessly a couple weeks ago.

When I run a PHP script through command line (a CRON job), the code that connects to the database (I'm using MySQL 5.7) gives the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

This happens to all users, no matter with or without passwords, even root.

The credentials ARE CORRECT. The same code (the database connection class) is used to generate some web content and it works fine. I'm using Apache 2.4, also I can connect via mysql cli or MySQL Workbench, so credentials and permissons seems not to be the problem here.

The line that creates a PDO instance is simple as this:

`new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);`

and the dsn is like:

`mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8`

(also tried with **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost** but had the same problem)

There's just one MySQL, PHP and Apache in the system, running Ubuntu 16.04, everything is in the same machine.

The only thing that changed during this time was an OpenSSL update, but I don't know if this could be related. I've seen some questions about this error but they are the opposite, works in CLI but not in apache, so I decided to make a new question.

More info:

- Both Apache and the CRON job itself are being executed by my user (faelv)
- The CRON job command is: `php dispatchCLI.php task=first`
- The apache and cli scripts uses the same includes (they both instantiates a class)
- `sudo` changes nothing

Comment: What user/group is executing the cron job with php vs running apache? What is the cron job php script and the apache php script (are they the same `include` files)?

Comment: Added more info as requested

Comment: Does the user in mysql have a specific value for Host like localhost? If so try changing it to `%` (meaning any host) and see if it works.

Comment: The mysql user has CRUD priviliges in all databases (it's a dev machine), I already tried using %, but no luck.

Comment: _“OpenSSL update, but I don't know if this could be related”_ - sounds rather unlikely to me (would expect a different error then), but compare what phpinfo has to say regarding the OpenSSL version in each case (CLI, and PHP via Apache, usually use different php.ini config files.)